# Trying to use an index in a razor for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code:

```
 @{ 
        var index=0;
        }
        @foreach (AdminSummary adminSummary in @Model.AdminSummaries) {
        index++;
        <div class="rep_tr0">
            <div class="rep_td0">@adminSummary.RowKey</div>
            <div class="rep_td0"><a href="/Administration/Products/Edit?&ac=@Model.Meta.AccountID&pr=@Model.Meta.ProductID&pa=@Model.Meta.PackageID&co=@adminSummary.RowKey">Edit</a></div>            
            <div class="rep_td0"><a href="/Administration/Products/Delete?&ac=@Model.Meta.AccountID&pr=@Model.Meta.ProductID&pa=@Model.Meta.PackageID&co=@adminSummary.RowKey">Delete</a></div>            
            <div class="rep_td0">@Html.TextBox("position_" index, @adminSummary.Position, new { size = 5 })</div>
            <div class="rep_td0">@adminSummary.Title</div>
            <div class="rep_td0">@adminSummary.DetailCount</div>
            <div class="rep_td0">@adminSummary.Modified</div> 
            <div class="rep_td0">@adminSummary.ModifiedBy</div> 

        </div>
    }
```

I am trying to find a good way to add an index value to the position name.

But this keeps giving me the error:   CS1026: ) expected for the line with position_ on

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**Update:**

I tried the following:

```
<div class="rep_td0">@Html.TextBox("position_"@(index), @adminSummary.Position, new { size = 5 })</div>
```

This gave the error: CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @

Comment: Can you give us a little more of the error dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="rep_td0">@Html.TextBox(string.Format("position_{0}", index), @adminSummary.Position, new { size = 5 })</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="rep_td0">@Html.TextBox("position_"+ index.ToString(), @adminSummary.Position, new { size = 5 })</div>
```

just replace this line with above.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your inserted razor in ()

```
<a href="http://mystuff/@(Model.Object.Stuff)/Screen">Example</a>
```

Also, sometimes if you are in a razor block, the compiler requires you to wrap html if it is the only thing on the line,like div tags, in

```
<text><div class="rep_tr0"></text>
```

EDIT: Sorry, misread the question a little, after index++

```
string textBoxId = "position_" + index;
```

THEN:

```
<div class="rep_td0">@Html.TextBox(@textBoxId, @adminSummary.Position, new { size = 5 })</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice, but instead `@foreach()`, try use `@for()`, then your loop has its own index.